# what languages are supported by UIsearchController?

Tags: ios, localization

I know UISearchController adapts the language of device and displays the default placeholder in that language. (For example: in English it is "Search")However, i'm setting my to device to my local language and it doesn't work.

Comment: What is your local language ?

Comment: my local language is Hebrew

Comment: There's nothing specific to UISearchController. Your app will support only those languages which you have explicitly added localizations for.